# What are N-grams?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, speech-recognition, n-gram

**What are N-grams?**

**I want to find N-grams for n=4 (fourgram), n=5 (fivegram), n=6 (sixgram), n=7(sevengram)** for the Sentence - "**dog that barks does not bite**"

I know-

Unigrams(n=1): dog, that, barks, does, not, bite

Bigrams(n=2): dog that, that barks, bark does, does not, not bite

Trigrams(n=3): dog that barks, that bark does, barks does not, does not bite

**How many N-grams can we find for the given sentence?**

Comment: An n-gram is simply a contiguous sequence of tokens (in this case, words) with length n drawn from a source document. 

In this case, since your source is 6 words long, the longest n-gram you can have is a 6-gram, which is equal to the entire string. I don't really see why you asked this question here though, since it's tangentially related to programming, at most.

Comment: n-grams are used in Machine Learning problem where you want classify documents (e.g. news documents) to their main categories (sports, politics, media, etc.)  For your kind information [read here](https://www.quora.com/How-are-N-grams-used-in-machine-learning)

Comment: @desertnaut why downvote?? this question is related to Machine Learning...

Comment: It is, but it is not related to *programming*, which SO is all about (why exactly the `python` tag? how is this a Python question?). Please notice that questions about general ML theory & methodology should be posted at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks for the information, i really don't know about [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). I will make sure to use [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) for ML questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

N-Grams is present for the sentence with at least 'N' no.of words. So, in your case "dog that barks does not bite" has 6 words, so you can frame 6-grams at most(1,2,3,4,5,6 - Grams) and not more than that. So, the result would be

- 4- gram : dog that barks does, that barks does not, barks does not
  bite,
- 5 - gram : dog that barks does not, that barks does not bite,
- 6 - gram : dog that barks does not bite